# Can a VLAN use both a trunk and an access port together?

Tags: switch, vlan

I'm trying to figure out if a VLAN can use both a trunk port and access port on a switch. If so, would the switch would be smart enough to figure out which packets to tag/untag? Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Yes, but the configuration directives will vary from vendor to vendor.  I have done that often, for PXE/kickstart on the untagged vlan and various other networks on the same port.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but the exact terminology will vary depending on which switch vendor you are using. On Cisco equipment it's the 'Native VLAN' most vendors will have something similar (and probably close to that name since most try to emulate the Cisco interface).